# How do I prevent certain URL patterns from being handled by Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm working on upgrading an application to Vaadin 24 and Spring Boot 3. The application includes a REST API that utilizes SpringDoc and OpenAPI 3.0. I need to prevent the `/api/**` and `/swagger-ui/**` URL patterns from being handled by Vaadin. To accomplish this, I have specified the following property in my `application.properties` file:

```
vaadin.exclude-urls=/api/**,/swagger-ui/**
```

However, when I visit a URL such as `/swagger-ui/index.html`, my browser displays a Vaadin page that says `Could not navigate to 'swagger-ui/index.html'`.

My `VaadinServlet` is mapped to the root mapping (`/*`) and I have verified that the other properties I have specified in `application.properties` are taking effect as expected.

Is there anything else I need to do to get the `vaadin.exclude-urls` property to work as expected?

Comment: The feature was introduced in 23.3. (https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12949) Maybe this is a regression bug.